# Best way to get the indexes of a minimum sum path dynamic programming approach?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Context: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/

A dynamic programming solution to this problem looks something like this:

```
from math import inf

def min_path(grid, y, x):

    matrix = [[0] * (y + 1) for _ in range(x + 1)]
    matrix[0][0] = grid[0][0]

    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, n in enumerate(row):
            if i == 0 and j == 0: 
               continue
            matrix[i][j] = grid[i][j] + min(i and matrix[i-1][j] or inf, j and matrix[i][j-1] or inf) 

    return matrix[x][y]

print(min_path([[1, 2, 3], 
                [4, 8, 2], 
                [1, 5, 3]], 2, 2))
```

However, this approach only returns the lowest/largest sum path. Is there a succinct way to also get the actual indexes of numbers making up the best path?

Comment: The code in post won't work (at least because of syntax error at line 10 - plus sign - and being inf not defined). Moreover, creating matrix like it's done here will lead to results you don't expect. `[0]*(x+1)` returns list, where all elements will change synchronously if any of them is changed, because they're referencing the same memory. But if you can fix that problems, getting path along with value is simple: just keep in grid tuples (length, full path as tuple or list) instead of single values. You can also create second matrix for storing paths, if you want.

Comment: Well, I'll look in 30 mins and try to post a code if no one will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep current path as second element of tuple. Note that comparison by `min()` will be performed by first element, so no additional key should be specified. Also with current problem we can omit the `tuple(tuple())`, because we'll never get this element as result due to used algorithm. I created a function to add tuples elementwise, you can also use numpy arrays instead or create lambda function and pass it instead of name like `(lambda x,y: tuple(x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(x))))(...)`.

```
from math import inf

def elwise(x,y):
    return tuple(x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(x)))

def min_path(grid, y, x):
    matrix = [[(0, ((i,j),)) 
        for j in range(y + 1)] 
        for i in range(x + 1)]
    matrix[0][0] = (grid[0][0], ((0,0),))

    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, n in enumerate(row):
            if i == j == 0: 
               continue
            matrix[i][j] = elwise(
                min(
                    i and matrix[i-1][j] or (inf,tuple(tuple())), 
                    j and matrix[i][j-1] or (inf,tuple(tuple()))), 
                (grid[i][j],((i,j),)))

    return matrix[x][y]

print(min_path([[1, 2, 3], 
                [4, 8, 2], 
                [1, 5, 3]], 2, 2))
```

This code prints the following:

```
(11, ((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)))
```